# Clear the same interval multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with this clearInterval method. Let me explain.

I have three javascript tabs, **LOW | MEDIUM | HIGH**.

When I go into the index page, the LOW tab is default open. And interval *AjaxLow* starts. Like this:

```
function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php", 
        success: (function (result) {
             var res = $.parseJSON(result);
             var str1 = "<center><img src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/";
            var str3 = " ' height='60' width='70'/></br>";
            var mes = [];
            var div = [];
            var totalLowPot = 0;
            for (kil = 0; kil < res[0].length; kil++) {
            mes[kil] = str1.concat(res[0][kil], str3)+res[1][kil]+"$</center>";
             $("#div"+kil).html(mes[kil]);  
             totalLowPot = totalLowPot + parseFloat(res[1][kil]);
             document.getElementById("totalLowPot").innerHTML = totalLowPot.toFixed(2);
            } 
            myChance(totalLowPot.toFixed(2));
            getLowPlayers();
        })
    })
};
var ajaxLow = setInterval(ajaxCall, (1 * 250)); // x * 1000 to get it in seconds
```

But when I click on another tab, e.g MEDIUM. The *ajaxLow* interval should stop. And it does since I am calling this function.

```
function clearLow() {
    clearInterval(ajaxLow);
}
```

here

```
<button class=tablink onclick="openCity('low',this,'#f1f1f1');" id=defaultOpen>LOW</button>
<button class=tablink onclick="openCity('medium',this,'#f1f1f1'); clearLow();">MEDIUM</button>
<button class=tablink onclick="openCity('high',this,'#f1f1f1')">HIGH</button>
```

But when I click back into the **LOW** tab, the interval didn't start again. So I tried calling the *ajaxLow;* again when you press on the LOW tab.

This is how I tried calling ajaxLow again:

```
<button class=tablink onclick="openCity('low',this,'#f1f1f1'); ajaxLow;" id=defaultOpen>LOW</button>
```

This is where the real problem appears, it refuses to clear the ajaxLow function again and it just keeps on running. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: I would suggest that you first move all your inline event handlers (`onclick`) out of the HTML and into JavaScript as proper event handlers that use `.addEventListener()`. Then, if we are to help, you'll need to post `openCity()`.

Comment: Also, why `(1 * 250)` and not just `250`?

Comment: " tried calling the ajaxLow; again when you press on the LOW tab."... did you? Where's that then? Show us what you did.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my internet went down. Please check the updated question.

Comment: `ajaxLow;` does not call ajaxlow, that would be `ajaxLow();`. that said `ajaxLow` is a `setinterval ` pointer, you can't call it. I think you want `ajaxCall()`

Comment: `ajaxLow;` makes no sense. That's just a variable name. It doesn't _do_ anything. If you want to re-start the interval, you need to make a call to setInterval.

Comment: If I only call ajaxCall() then it won't be set into an interval.

Comment: yeah so you need to run setInterval. Right now you only ever call setInterval when your page loads, and never afterwards. If you want to declare a new interval (because you cleared the last one), then you need to call setInterval. It's not complicated.